# Priority Queue Generic

Tags: java, generics, priority-queue

So I recently learnt about Generics and thought it would be cool to implement them in a Priority Queue. I am having a "Block" element which has a firstName and a data variable. The Node for the Priority Queue consists of Block, Next and Prev.

I am attaching the code below. I am almost exclusively getting "Should be parametrized" errors/warnings. And an error which says that my "Data" element cannot be resolved to a field, which probably means that I am unable to tell that I want Block as my "element E" in a Node. Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated

```
package QGen;

public class Block<E> implements Comparable<Block<E>> {
    protected String firstName;
    protected int data;

    public Block(String firstName, int data) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.data = data;

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Block x) {
        return (this.data - x.data);
    }
}


package QGen;

public class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable> {
    protected Node<E> firstSentinel;
    protected Node<E> lastSentinel;

    protected class Node<E> {
        protected Node<E> next;
        protected Node<E> prev;
        private E element;

        public Node(E e, Node<E> previous, Node<E> nextt) {
            element = e;
            prev = previous;
            next = nextt;
        }
    }

    public PriorityQueue() {
        firstSentinel = new Node<>(null, null, null);
        lastSentinel = new Node<>(null, null, null);
        firstSentinel.data = 11111;
        lastSentinel.data = 0;
        firstSentinel.prev = null;
        firstSentinel.next = lastSentinel;
        lastSentinel.prev = firstSentinel;
        lastSentinel.next = null;
    }

    public void enQueue(E x) {
        Node<E> newX = new Node<E>(x, null, null);
        if (firstSentinel.next == lastSentinel)// list is empyty
        {
            firstSentinel.next = newX;
            newX.prev = firstSentinel;
            newX.next = lastSentinel;
            lastSentinel.prev = newX;
        } else {
            Node<E> temp = newX;
            Node<E> curr = firstSentinel.next;
            while (curr != lastSentinel && temp.element.compareTo(curr) <= 0) {// <=comparison
                // replaced
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            Node<E> tempCurr = curr;
            temp.next = tempCurr;
            temp.prev = tempCurr.prev;
            tempCurr.prev.next = temp;
            tempCurr.prev = temp;

        }
    }

    public E deQueue() {
        if (firstSentinel.next == lastSentinel) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(null, null, null);
            temp = firstSentinel.next;
            firstSentinel.next = temp.next;
            temp.next.prev = firstSentinel;
            return temp.element;
        }
    }

    public void printt() {
        Node<E> temp = new Node<E>(null, null, null);
        temp = firstSentinel.next;
        while (temp != lastSentinel) {
            System.out
                    .println(temp.element.firstName + " " + temp.element.data);

            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}

package QGen;

public class containsMain<E> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PriorityQueue<Block> example = new PriorityQueue<Block>();
        Block dequedObject = new Block<>(null, null);
        Block<Block> incomingName = new Block<>("r", 1);
        example.enQueue(incomingName);
        dequedObject = (Block) example.deQueue();

    }

}
```

I am aware that my PriorityQueue might not be the best of implementations and I will improve it. It is the Generics where I am unable to come up with a solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the logic of your methods, I have several remarks regarding generics:

why is Block itself generic? It doesnt hold any generic field so remove it from Block!

```
new Node<>(null, null, null);
// this is a bad idea, change it to new Node<E>(null, null, null)


firstSentinel.data = 11111;
lastSentinel.data = 0;

//Those two cant work, because firstSentinel is referencing a Node<E> and not a Block! Delete those two rows, as they make no sense in your generic implementation of the Queue

Block<Block> incomingName = new Block<>("r", 1); 
// This doesnt make sense, should be Block incomingName = new Block(...)
```